# css nth-child, every 3rd + 1, ie: 4, 7, 10, 13, etc

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have been trying to figure this out, but no success - for now have this as a placeholder that works, but it's fugly...

```
.customField:nth-child(4), 
.customField:nth-child(7), 
.customField:nth-child(10), 
.customField:nth-child(13), 
.customField:nth-child(16) {
  clear: both;
}
```

How get I get this to on `nth-child` statement?

Comment: You're very, very close.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every 3rd child is `3n` but to start on the 4th one, use `4` as an offset.

```css
div:nth-child(3n + 4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
<div>asdf</div>
```

Comment: Thought I had tried that - but revisited and this did the trick, thanks!

Comment: IF you want to include the first one its `:nth-child(3n-2)`

Comment: @Tristanisginger Exactly the solution for the problem I was having!

Answer (score 4):

I believe `:nth-child(3n+4)` would work.

The general format is `:nth-child(an+b)` for a given value of `n` where `n` is a positive number or zero.